# Пагинатор на php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Итак, в интернете есть много инструкций, скриптов как сделать пагинатор для постраничного вывода из базы mysql, типа 1, 2, 3...

Мне же нужно чтобы на сайте было две кнопки (вперед и назад).
На сайт выводится 10 записей и при нажатии кнопки вперед выводятся следующие 10 записей...

А когда записи в таблице кончились чтоб кнопка вперед пропадала..
То есть я не хочу выводить номера страниц и т.п. Мне нужно только 2 кнопки.
Кто знает, как можно это сделать пожалуйста отпишитесь, примеры скриптов, сайты с подобным контентом не помешают...

Comment: Как вариант, можно взять подходящий пагинатор, у которого помимо всего прочего есть кнопки "Вперёд" и "Назад", и убрать из него всё "лишнее".

Comment: Streletz А где мне взять такой "подходящий" пагинатор?

Comment: В интернете полно исходников.

Comment: Не плохой ответ...

Comment: Вместо того чтобы помочь

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Помочь, вовсе не значит дать готовое. Да и гуглить за кого-то никому не интересно. При такой постановке вопроса это вполне естественно. Либо выкладывайте Ваши наработки с конкретным описанием проблемы.